# I want know Gin Framwork function, which is similar to http.Get and http.Post

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, oauth, bind

In Develop Oauth authorization, I faced Binding Problem

```golang
var googleOauthConfig = &model.OauthConfig{
    Client_id:     os.Getenv("webclient_id"),
    Client_secret: "",
    Redirect_uri:  info.GoogleRedirectPath,
    Grant_type:    "authorization_code",
}
const RequestGoogleToken string = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"

type Token struct {
    Access_token  string    `json:"access_token" binding:"required"`
    Token_type    string    `json:"token_type" binding:"required"`
    Expiration    time.Time `json:"expires_in" binding:"required"`
    Refresh_token string    `json:"refresh_token" binding:"required"`
}
```

I have to Request to Method "POST" in RequestGoogleToken URI and Get Token struct data

and I can use this way

```golang
token := &model.Token{}
pbytes, _ := json.Marshal(token)
buff := bytes.NewBuffer(pbytes)
resp, err := http.Post(info.RequestGoogleToken, "application/json", buff)
```

I used http Function "POST" and I can Get data type of []byte
and I cant bind Token Struct

I want gin framework Method, and I'd appreciate it if you suggest any idea

Comment: Gin is a server library, not a client library. Just use `encoding/json` to unmarshal the data.

Comment: Thank you !! I used json.Unmarshal and I can handle it

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I couldn't find any of gin's internal functionality to cater it (maybe my research is incomplete). But here is how I handled it.
You can use a map[string]interface{} with json.NewDecoder
To get an idea:

```
 resp, err := http.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token=" +
            url.QueryEscape(token.AccessToken)) 



 var respJSON map[string]interface{}
            err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&respJSON)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
```

Now the respJSON will contain the fields returned from http.Get request.
In my case, I was getting email of the user via oauth from facebook, so my respJSON map would contain

```
respJSON["email"] // would yield the user's email
```

then I created an object of user, and set the email and other fields myself.